# Server reverts to DHCP from time to time

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, ip-address, ifconfig

I have an Ubuntu 10.04 server with static IP address configuration:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.51
network 192.168.2.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.2.255
gateway 192.168.2.1
```

From time to time (between once a month or once every 3 days depending on load) the server will spontaneously discard this IP address and change to one configured via DHCP.

When this happens I need to SSH into the server (using its `.local` hostname) and do `/etc/init.d/networking restart` to get it to use the static IP again.

How can this happen, and more importantly, how can I stop it?

Comment: I would suggest you installing `auditd` to see 'who' made changes to the `/etc/networking/interfaces`.

Comment: @quanta I made the file, but that's not the problem. The file doesn't change, just the actual IP address does.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that there is a DHCP client process still running?

Perhaps you changed the server from DHCP to static, performed a network restart but the dhclient process didn't exit correctly.

You can do

```
johnf@zoot:~$ ps ax | grep [d]hclient
28248 ?        S      0:00 /sbin/dhclient # Other args
```

to check.

If so kill this process off or reboot.

Comment: I can check but I'm pretty sure the server has been rebooted multiple times since it was given a static IP.

Answer (score 0):

Why not configure the DHCP server to hand out the IP address you want based on the server's MAC address? With ISC dhcpd (the de-facto standard DHCP server for unix systems) just put something like this in the config (make sure that subnet mask and gateway are already configured properly):

```
host server01
{
    hardware ethernet MA:CA:DD:RE:SS;
    fixed-address 192.168.2.51;
    option host-name "server01";
}
```

Comment: The server is actually in a small business network with a consumer router-modem, but it's a Linksys so maybe a static lease is possible. Still, it shouldn't be necessary. Another server in the same network is configured with a static IP the same way, and it never has problems.